# Generate Signed APK not active in build menu android studio

Tags: android-studio

Generate Signed APK not active in build menu android studio!

[image: see here]

Comment: Please add more details, like why do you need the APK, and related error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happened because you're using an incorrect version of Android Gradle plugin. There is no version `3.2.1` yet. So, change your project/root build.gradle with version `3.2.0` (take a look [Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) for more details):

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      google()

      ...
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
   }
}
```

Then sync your project after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project build without any error. And Whenever you open Project Level Gradle then Generate Signed Apk , Select Build Variant Options are not available.